# best data structure suitable for event-calender application

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashmap, binary-search-tree

I have a class which represents an event.
so we can create an event by creating a object of this class. constructor takes `description, start time, end time, list of invites, location` and return an id for uniquely identifying this object.

```
Create events : (description, start time, end time, list of invites, location) -> id
```

Now this class has another method which takes an id and return a corresponding event object

`Get event by id : id -> event object`

similarly we can update an event

`Update event -> description, start time, end time`

now 4th operation we want to do is that we want to filter out all the events between a time range

`get event : start time, end time`

Now I have to use/design a data structure which can perform these 4 operations efficiently. (I mean we are now allowed to use File storage or Caching technologies)

for 1st three operations I thought I can use Has map/table which will be having `id` as a key and object as a value.
but in this case I wont be able to perform 4th operation efficiently.

for that again I though I could use `trie` data structure.

```
Root Node->
      Month nodes (12 nodes)
      each month node will be having 30(or 31/28) children nodes. 
      and then those children nodes will be having time stamp nodes.
```

but in this case 1st three operations become bit inefficient.

How can I combine these two data structure to solve this problem and perform all 4 operations efficient.  or is there any better data structure which can do this task. or we have to create our own custom data structure?

Answer (score 1):

As you have said you can use a `hashmap` for the first tree operations. For the 4th operation you can maintain a sorted list of `(start_time_of_event,id)`. Now for finding all the events between `(start,end)` you can use two binary searchs on this sorted array and find all the events between `(start,end)`. This method has a little space overhead because you just need to store a copy of `id` and `start_date` of event.